# Log files are't shown in TFS web interface

Tags: logging, tfs, msbuild

I currently working on a custom build template for my team foundation server. Since I run MSBuild twice for a project during a single build, the log files are not linked in the build summary of the web interface anymore as you can see below.

I already changed the name of the LogFile property of msbuid, but it does not help.

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: Are you copying the output to a drop folder?

Comment: Yes I do, but I want to get the log files directly from the build summary.